# Changing screen aspect ratio output on android devices

Tags: android, output, screen, aspect-ratio

I'm developing an application for an Android set-top box which has HDMI and composite video outputs. The set-top box always outputs a signal that has 16:9 aspect ratio. When the set-top box is connected to a TV with 4:3 aspect ratio, all of the UI elements look squeezed. Can the aspect ratio of the output signal be changed programatically in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the firmware level? Conceivably. That would be the job of the manufacturer of the set-top box.

At the SDK level? No.